# Chirp with linearly changing frequency and amplitude?

Tags: signal-processing, time-series, trigonometric-series

A linear [chirp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Linear_chirp)

[image]

or linearly swept sine is a signal 
in which the frequency changes linearly with time:

the starting frequency  [image] changes into the ending frequency [image] over time 
at a rate of:

[image]

and [image] is the amount of time it takes. Its instantaneous frequency at point t is:

[image]

It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a similar equation where you can make the amplitude also change with time, independently of the changing frequency? It would have this shape approximately:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: $f(t)\cos(\omega(t))$?

Comment: I don't think so. Ideally I would also define an A0 and A1: the starting and ending amplitude, so the amplitude "line" goes from (1,A0) to (T,A1), so the equation of this line would be: y-A0=(A1-A0)/(T-1)(x-1). Thinking of the standard equation of a sinusoid, which is A*sin*(2pi*f*t+theta0), in that case you first multiply with the amplitude. So instead of a constant, it would be the equation of the amplitude line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a time-dependent amplitude function $A(t)>0$, as already pointed out in a comment:

$$x(t)=A(t)\sin(\omega t+\phi)$$

The function $A(t)$ can have any form as long as it is positive (because it must be an amplitude). If you want it to decrease linearly from value $A_0>0$ at time $t_0$ to $A_1$ ($0<A_1<A_0$) at time $t_1$, simply define it as

$$A(t)=\frac{A_1-A_0}{t_1-t_0}(t-t_0)+A_0$$

Comment: Could you use this "linear amplitude & frequency chirp" function to do a regression to estimate the instantaneous frequency of a smooth curve in real time (online analysis)?

Comment: @MisterH: To be honest, I do not know ...